# Unable to access TempData inside my HandleUnauthorizedRequest

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, tempdata

I have created my own customization for the AuthorizeAttribute inside my asp.net mvc web application, and to be able to return the user to the current URL after login , i am trying to save the current URL inside a TempData and then redirect to the login action method ,as follow-

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!_authorize && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var viewResult = new RedirectResult("/Account/Login");
                TempData["returnUrl"] = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;


                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

                filterContext.Result = viewResult;
            }
```

but seesm that i can not reference TempData in this case, because the above code will raise the following error:-

> The name 'TempData' does not exist in the current context

Can anyone advice please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using controller base,

```
filterContext.Controller.TempData["returnUrl"] = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
```

Also `TempData` may behave unexpectedly in Authorize attribute as it lives only on one request cycle. If so use `Session` instead.

Comment: but in my case i only need it inside the redirected Login action method only... thanks